# How to optimize read performance of S3 when using GZip input files for Hadoop

Tags: optimization, hadoop, amazon-s3, hadoop-streaming

I am getting very dismal performance at the first step of my Hadoop streaming job: it seems to me that the mappers read from S3 around 40KB/s - 50KB/s.

**It takes over an hour for ~100MB of data to be read from S3**!

The way that data is stored: thousands of ~5-10KB GZip files in the S3 bucket.

I recently decompressed all the files of a sample 100MB dataset and uploaded it as a single GZip file in the same S3 bucket, and my task finished in 3 mins (vs previous 1 hour runs)

Encouraged, I decompressed all the files of a sample 2GB dataset and uploaded it as a single GZip file in the same S3 bucket, and **my task again took more than 1 hour: after which I terminated the task**.

I have not played around with `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size`, but I need some sample values to start playing around with.

From the posts I read on the internet though, it seems processing GBs of data with GZip input files for Hadoop streaming tasks does not incur a lot of penalty as far as reading them off S3 is concerned.

Could you share:

1. the "blob size" of the files you store on S3 and
2. how many of those you process per task and
3. how long processing those take?

I am guessing tuning the `mapred.min.split.size` and `mapred.max.split.size` and keeping the above 3 values optimal regards to S3 will make a lot of change in the time of execution of the jobs.

Answer (score 0):

Reading a gzipped file cannot be parallelized. By concatenating all your files into one huge file and gzipping it you created a bottleneck. Your best performance you can get by concatenating and individually gzipping your files in a way that compressed files are about the same size, they are not smaller than 128Mb and the number of the files equals the number of reducers on your Hadoop cluster.

Comment: Is there some external tool/script that, given an input path, will compress every batch of uncompressed 100MB files into a single gzip file?